# Will CORS prevent a browser accessing an URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

If a activate CORS on my .NET core application, will then users be able to access a endpoint by putting an URL in their own browser (for e.g. https://example.com/api/Account/ExternalLogin?client_id)? Or does CORS only preventing javascript to make requests?

Comment: CORS prevents Only javascript request.

Comment: For more information about CORS, you can check this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: The CORS protocol is enforced only by browsers. It’s not enforced by servers. It’s not the case that if there’s some lack of any CORS details in a request, servers somehow block requests, or refuse to send responses.Instructions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 1):

CORS is a mechanism enforced within browsers, not servers. The server can indicate to browsers what should be allowed, but ultimately it is up to the browser to enforce that. Hence, servers should always authenticate and authorize every request regardless of CORS.

To answer your specific question, yes, any client can attempt to access any endpoint on your server. Only cooperative browsers will prevent that in certain circumstances. It's always possible to request a URL directly via the address bar, regardless of CORS.

Comment: No browser will ever prevent user from putting an url on the address bar. Cors doesn't even matter here. Note that the question is very specific but your answer seems to miss this specificity.

Comment: Thanks, I added that additional clarification.

Comment: So browser blocks server's response for the JavaScript requests. Direct requests from address bar are not related to CORS and they work all the time irrespective of the origin ? @WiktorZychla